# Reload pfobejct in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, segue, pfobject

I have a Parse class containing data, this is loaded into a tableview and made into a pfobject and the data is displayed, I also have the pfobject passed to a detail view via prepare for segue from the tableview. What I am wanting to do is segue to the detail view from any other view not just the tableview and display the same data. THe problem I have is the object is only passed to the detail view in the segue from the tableview so if i segue from any other view to the detail view it doesn't have an object to unwrap. heres the code to pass the object and how it is read.

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

```
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    let detailView = segue.destinationViewController as! PlantsDetailView



    // Pass the selected object to the destination view controller.
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let row = Int(indexPath.row)
        detailView.currentObject = (objects?[row])! as PFObject
    }
```

how its read:

```
    // Unwrap the current object object
    if let object = currentObject {
        self.title = object["plantName"] as? String
        about.text = object["Description"] as? String
```

Comment: let dvc = YourViewController();   dvc.object = yourPFObject;   self.presentViewController(dvc, animated:true);   you need to pass the PFObject before you actually present the View Controller.

Comment: would you be able to edit my code with this in as I am getting errors, thanks